# How to create slice with specific length?

Tags: go, slice

Are these 3 ways to create slice of specific length identical? Are there any differences about something like performance and garbage collection among them?

```golang
s := make([]byte, 4)
```

```golang
s := []byte{0, 0, 0, 0}
```

```golang
var base [4]byte
s := base[:]
```

Comment: Use #1. #2 is useful when you want to initialize the slice with values other than zero. #3 is wasteful, misleading.

Comment: Have you tried each of them and compared their performance and memory efficiency in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

The second param is size specifies the length.
The third param is capacity of the slice is:

```
    s := make([]byte,0,4)
```